# Controlling Web Service Serialization

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, serialization

In my web service, I have the following class

```
public class ContactDetails
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    public List<string> PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Which, as it is, returns the following data in the XML output

```
<ContactDetails>
    <Name>MR SMITH</Name>
    <Address>I HIGH STREET, SOMETOWN</Address>
    <Postcode>AA1 2BB</Postcode>
    <PhoneNumber>
        <string>01234 567890</string>
        <string>01234 567890</string>
    </PhoneNumber>
</ContactDetails>
```

Obviously, we want the phone numbers to be more sensible structured within PhoneNumbers>PhoneNumber and cannot seem to quite get it right.

We have added the XmlElement markup, which is almost there; such that

```
public class ContactDetails
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "PC")]
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "PhoneNumber")]
    public List<string> PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Produces the following

```
<ContactDetails>
    <Name>MR SMITH</Name>
    <Address>I HIGH STREET, SOMETOWN</Address>
    <PC>AA1 2BB</PC>
    <PhoneNumber></PhoneNumber>
    <PhoneNumber></PhoneNumber>
</ContactDetails>
```

But as you see, we have now lost the nesting for the phone numbers ... the desired output would be:

```
<ContactDetails>
    <Name>MR SMITH</Name>
    <Address>I HIGH STREET, SOMETOWN</Address>
    <PC>AA1 2BB</PC>
    <PhoneNumbers>
        <PhoneNumber></PhoneNumber>
        <PhoneNumber></PhoneNumber>
    </PhoneNumbers>
</ContactDetails>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attributes you want to use are:

1. [`XmlArrayAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) -- controls the outer name of a two-level list.
2. [`XmlArrayItemAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - controls the inner name of a two-level list.

Thus:

```
public class ContactDetails
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    [XmlArray("PhoneNumbers")]
    [XmlArrayItem("PhoneNumber")]
    public List<string> PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```